# How to apply the linear gradient to the Header, using the native base. (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I start practice the react native, I have question regarding linear gradient of react, how to apply the Linear gradient color to the header of native base.

I have create sample Linear gradient

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#00e4d0', '#5983e8']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            Sign in with Facebook
          </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
```

The question how to set the linear gradient color to the header?

```
<View style={styles.container}>

        <Header style={{backgroundColor:'#00e4d0'}}>

          <Left style={styles.headerLeft}>
            <Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} style={{color:'white'}}></Icon>
          </Left>

          <Body>
            <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 25}}>Hiflyer</Text>
          </Body>

        </Header>

        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>

          <Text>Home</Text>

        </View>

        <LinearGradient colors={['#00e4d0', '#5983e8']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            Sign in with Facebook
          </Text>
        </LinearGradient>

    </View>
```

Answer (score -2):

Is the `LinearGradient` from expo? In that case
just wrap your `LinearGradient` component around the Header component.

For Example,

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#00e4d0', '#5983e8']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
       <Header style={{backgroundColor:'#00e4d0'}}>

          <Left style={styles.headerLeft}>
            <Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} style={{color:'white'}}></Icon>
          </Left>

          <Body>
            <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 25}}>Hiflyer</Text>
          </Body>

        </Header>

</LinearGradient>
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you might wanna use `react-native-linear-gradient`

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
```

And the last but most important thing set some `flex` value to your `LinearGradient`,

```
<LinearGradient 
     colors={['#6e45e2', '#88d3ce']}
     style = { styles.container }
>
   <Header style={{backgroundColor:'#00e4d0'}}>

      <Left style={styles.headerLeft}>
        <Icon name="menu" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} style={{color:'white'}}></Icon>
      </Left>

      <Body>
        <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize: 25}}>Hiflyer</Text>
      </Body>

   </Header>

</LinearGradient>
```